# Java - extending on a simple recursive descent parser

Tags: java, parsing, recursion

I've written this simple recursive parser method that evaluates simple arithmetic expressions (consisting of only +, -, *, and /).

However, I am currently stuck on a few things:

1. How do I implement the recognition of parentheses?
2. How do I implement the recognition of unary operators? e.g. unary minus (-) and factorial (!)
3. How do I implement the recognition of functions? e.g. sin(x)

   ```
   private static double eval(String s) {

       if (s.charAt(0) == '-' || s.charAt(0) == '+') {
           s = "0" + s;
       }

       if (s.indexOf("+") > -1) {
           return (eval(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("+"))) + eval(s.substring(s.indexOf("+") + 1, s.length())));
       } else if (s.indexOf("-") > -1) {
           return (eval(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("-"))) - eval(s.substring(s.indexOf("-") + 1, s.length())));
       } else if (s.indexOf("*") > -1) {
           return (eval(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("*"))) * eval(s.substring(s.indexOf("*") + 1, s.length())));
       } else if (s.indexOf("/") > -1) {
           return (eval(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("/"))) / eval(s.substring(s.indexOf("/") + 1, s.length())));
       } else if (s.indexOf("^") > -1) {
           return (Math.pow(evaluate(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("^"))), evaluate(s.substring(s.indexOf("^") + 1, s.length()))));
       }

       return Double.parseDouble(s);
   }
   ```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you heard of Reverse Polish Notation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation Or it has to be recursive?

Comment: Yeah I've done a mathematical parser using a stack (converting from infix to postfix using shuntingyard). This one just has to be recursive :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like broad one but I'll try to put here my thought instead unreadable comment.

1. Looking for parantheses can be tricky because there are ones used for precedence and other for function arguments. What I'd do is to first look for '('. If it follows function, then skip it, otherwise go through all characters that follow until number of '(' == ')' and that would be what you pass to eval, everything before , between () and after ) would go to separate call to eval().
2. For unary operator '-' you'll most likely need to lookup previous character in you expression. Something like:

   ```
   } else if (s.indexOf("-") > -1) { // keeping this index would make more sense now
      if char at index -1 from '-' in list of characters indicating unary operator
         return -eval(s.substring(s.indexOf("-")+1, s.length())));

   else {
   return (eval(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("-"))) - 
     eval(s.substring(s.indexOf("-") + 1, s.length())));
       }
   }
   ```

These characters would absolutely be parantheses, other operators or if '-' had index 0. Just ask yourself how do you recognize unary operator and apply the same rules here.

The same approach would be for '!':

```
if(s.indexOf("!") > -1) {
    return fact(eval(s.substring(s.indexOf("-") + 1, s.length())));
}
```

**EDIT:**
As the OP correctly noticed, this approach would skip some expression parts so what's to be done for both functions and unary operators:

```
return eval(everything before + eval(expression)+ everything after);
```

3. Functions look exactly like unary operators, you only need to figure out precedence, so just put recognition of 'sin(' before looking for operators. Then apply the same approach as with unary operators.
   If you find function you remove the last closing parantheses.

   ```
   return fun(eval(rest of expression));
   ```

Hope those thoughts help you a bit.

Comment: I don't quite understand how your logic with the unary minus works - the line where it says `return -eval(s.substring(s.indexOf("-")+1, s.length()));`?

Comment: It means evaluate expression to the right of '-' and change sign to '-'. When I think of it, for recursion it would make more sense to replace call to unary operator and then evaluate expression. See edited pts2 & 3.

Comment: but then wouldn't the stuff to the left of '-' be ignored?

Comment: `return eval(everything before + eval(expression)+ everything after);` <- what would that look like if I were to implement the unary minus?

Comment: You split string on unary '-'. What's before goes here as a string. Expression being argument to '-' would be :1) function or 2) number. covering those 2 cases , what's left goes as after the expression. Expressions in parentheses would be covered earlier, so you would have - for number already. It's not that trivial to make it work recursively, that's why I suggested stacked approach.